# How can I add a HyperLink in TRichEdit using Delphi

Tags: delphi, hyperlink, vcl, richedit

How can I add a HyperLink in a `TRichEdit` within VCL (using Delphi Programming Language).

I need to have something like:

"This is my text, [click here](https://example.com) to do something."

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37792354/650492

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/l/aa111803a.htm) article on [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com)

> Unfortunately, Delphi's implementation of the RichEdit control leaves out a lot of the functionality found in more recent versions of this control (from Microsoft).

You can add your own functionality as discussed [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/l/aa111803a.htm).

NOTE: [Delphi 2009](http://www.codegear.com/products/delphi/win32) has just been released, so the TRichEdit control may have been updated to support mode features.

Answer (score 3):

i don't know if it's mentioned in the About.com article but i think it's worth mentioning that the hyperlink in TRichEdit only works if the TRichEdit itself is directly placed on the form (not in a panel).

http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0146.htm

Comment: It is mentioned in the about.com article; they even present a workaround for it.