# RichEdit does not process hyperlinks

Tags: delphi, hyperlink, richedit

I want my RichEdit to process hyperlinks, so I followed the instructions on: http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/l/aa111803a.htm

Here are the changes I made to the code:

```
interface

type
  TProgCorner = class(TForm)
    RichEdit2: TRichEdit;
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    RichEdit3: TRichEdit;
    RichEdit4: TRichEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure InitRichEditURLDetection(RE: TRichEdit);
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage); override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

uses
  ShellAPI, RichEdit;

const
  AURL_ENABLEURL = 1;
  AURL_ENABLEEAURLS = 8;

procedure TProgCorner.InitRichEditURLDetection(RE: TRichEdit);
var
  mask: LResult;
begin
  mask := SendMessage(RE.Handle, EM_GETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
  //In the debugger mask is always 1, for all 4 Richedits.
  SendMessage(RE.Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, mask or ENM_LINK); 
  //returns 67108865
  SendMessage(RE.Handle, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, AURL_ENABLEURL, 0);
  //Returns 0 = success (according to MSDN), but no joy.
  //SendMessage(RE.Handle, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, AURL_ENABLEEAURLS, 0); 
  //When uncommented returns -2147024809
  //I don't think the registration works, but don't know how to fix this.
end;

procedure TProgCorner.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  p: TENLink;
  sURL: string;
  CE: TRichEdit;
begin
  //'normal' messages do get through here, but...
  if (Msg.Msg = WM_NOTIFY) then begin
    //...the following line is never reached.
    if (PNMHDR(Msg.lParam).code = EN_LINK) then begin
      p:= TENLink(Pointer(TWMNotify(Msg).NMHdr)^);
      if (p.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) then begin
        try
          CE:= TRichEdit(ProgCorner.ActiveControl);
          SendMessage(CE.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, LPARAM(@(p.chrg)));
          sURL:= CE.SelText;
          ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(sURL), 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        except
          {ignore}
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

 inherited;
end;

procedure TProgCorner.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InitRichEditURLDetection(RichEdit1);
  InitRichEditURLDetection(RichEdit2);
  InitRichEditURLDetection(RichEdit3);
  InitRichEditURLDetection(RichEdit4);
  //If I set the text here (and not in the object inspector) 
  //the richedit shows a hyperlink with the 'hand' cursor.
  //but still no WM_notify message gets received in WndProc.
  RichEdit1.Text:= 'http://www.example.com';

end;

end.
```

However the hyperlinks that I embedded into my `RichEditx.Lines` using the object inspector show up as plain text (not links) and clicking on them does not work.

I'm using Delphi Seattle running on Windows 7 in Win32 mode.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
Using a combination of issuing the deprecated
`SendMessage(RE.Handle, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, AURL_ENABLEURL, 0);` and setting the `RichEditx.Text:= 'http://www.example.com'` manually in `FormCreate` I am able to have the Richedit display a hyperlink and handcursor.
However the WndProc still does not receive a `WM_Notify` message.
The WndProc does receive other messages.

**UPDATE2**
In my eagerness to simplify the issue I left out the fact that the `RichEdit` sits on top of a `Panel`. The panel eats the `WM_Notify` messages so they don't reach the form underneigh.

Comment: `mask` should be declared as `LResult`.

Comment: `SendMessage(CE.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, Longint(@(p.chrg)));` should be `SendMessage(CE.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, LPARAM(@(p.chrg)));`

Comment: @LURD, Updated, but this is win32, so that's not the issue, anyway I figured that the WM_Notify got intercepted and indeed it was.

Comment: @Johan: Your analysis is wrong. If the Form is the immediate `Parent` of a RichEdit then the Form's `WndProc()` *DOES* get called with the RichEdit's `WM_NOTIFY` messages. What you are not taking into account is that the VCL may have to re-create the RichEdit's `HWND` at times, thus losing your `EM_SETEVENTMASK` and `EM_AUTOURLDETECT` settings. Every time a RichEdit's `HWND` is recreated, you have to issue those messages again. Override the RichEdit's `CreateWnd()` method to handle that. And yes, intercepting `CN_NOTIFY` inside of the `TRichEdit` is best, but it is not the only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code shown in your question works perfect for me **as-is**.  Despite your claim, the Form's `WndProc()` does receive the `EN_LINK` notifications and launches the clicked URLs, as expected.

However, if you place a RichEdit on another parent control, like a `TPanel`, then the Form will not receive the `WM_NOTIFY` message anymore.  The parent control will receive them, and as such you will have to subclass that parent control instead.

That being said, there are a few improvements that can be made to the code shown:

1. in your `EN_LINK` handling, you can replace this:

   ```
   CE := TRichEdit(ProgCorner.ActiveControl);
   ```

   with this instead:

   ```
   CE := TRichEdit(FindControl(TWMNotify(Msg).NMHdr.hwndFrom));
   ```

   The notification tells you the `HWND` of the RichEdit control that is sending it, and the VCL knows how to retrieve a `TWinControl` from an `HWND`.
2. use [`EM_GETTEXTRANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774199.aspx) to retrieve the clicked URL, instead of using `EM_EXSETSEL` and `SelText` (which is a combination of `EM_EXGETSEL` and `EM_GETTEXTEX`).  This way, you are using fewer messages, and don't have to manipulate the RichEdit's selected text at all.  The notification tells you the exact range of characters for the URL, so you can just grab those characters directly.
3. you need to handle `HWND` recreation.  The VCL *may* recreate a RichEdit's `HWND` at any time.  Every time a new `HWND` is created, you have to send your `EM_SETEVENTMASK` and `EM_AUTOURLDETECT` messages again, otherwise you will lose your auto-detection.  The best way to handle this is to derive a class from `TRichEdit` and override its `CreateWnd()` method.
4. Since you have to derive a class anyway, you can have it handle the VCL's `CN_NOTIFY` message, instead of handling the original `WM_NOTIFY` message directly in the parent's `WndProc`. The VCL knows how to redirect a `WM_NOTIFY` message to the VCL control that sent it.  This allows VCL controls to handle their own notifications.  Thus, your `EN_LINK` handler will work no matter what parent control the RichEdit is placed on, you don't have to subclass/override the parent's `WndProc()` at all, and you can use the `Self` pointer of the RichEdit that is processing the message when accessing members of the RichEdit, such as its `Handle` property.

With all of that said, the following code works for me:

```
unit RichEditUrlTest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TRichEdit = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TRichEdit)
  private
    procedure CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotify); message CN_NOTIFY;
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  end;

  TProgCorner = class(TForm)
    RichEdit2: TRichEdit;
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    RichEdit3: TRichEdit;
    RichEdit4: TRichEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  ProgCorner: TProgCorner;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Winapi.ShellAPI, Winapi.RichEdit;

const
  AURL_ENABLEURL = 1;
  AURL_ENABLEEAURLS = 8;

procedure TRichEdit.CreateWnd;
var
  mask: LResult;
begin
  inherited;
  mask := SendMessage(Handle, EM_GETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
  SendMessage(Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, mask or ENM_LINK);
  SendMessage(Handle, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, AURL_ENABLEURL, 0);
end;

procedure TRichEdit.CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotify);
type
  PENLink = ^TENLink;
var
  p: PENLink;
  tr: TEXTRANGE;
  url: array of Char;
begin
  if (Message.NMHdr.code = EN_LINK) then begin
    p := PENLink(Message.NMHdr);
    if (p.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) then begin
      { optionally, enable this:
      if CheckWin32Version(6, 2) then begin
        // on Windows 8+, returning EN_LINK_DO_DEFAULT directs
        // the RichEdit to perform the default action...
        Message.Result :=  EN_LINK_DO_DEFAULT;
        Exit;
      end;
      }
      try
        SetLength(url, p.chrg.cpMax - p.chrg.cpMin + 1);
        tr.chrg := p.chrg;
        tr.lpstrText := PChar(url);
        SendMessage(Handle, EM_GETTEXTRANGE, 0, LPARAM(@tr));
        ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar(url), 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
      except
        {ignore}
      end;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TProgCorner.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RichEdit1.Text:= 'http://www.example.com';
end;

end.
```

Comment: Could you please provide the numeric value for the "EN_LINK_DO_DEFAULT" constant? I have looked in a number of "Richedit.h" files online and couldn't find it defined anywhere.

Alternatively I have tried a lot of consecutive values for it (from 0 to 32K) in the Mouse_Move event handler when hovering over the hyperlink but it didn't seem to perform the alleged "default action" for any of them...

Comment: @VanGoghGaming Sorry, I don't have the numeric value of `EN_LINK_DO_DEFAULT` handy.

Comment: Frankly I doubt it even exists because I've never encountered a constant for which the numeric value is nowhere do be found on the Internet. Maybe its functionality was removed in Windows 10? Who knows...

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the WM_Notify message never reaches the mainform.
Instead it gets intercepted by the parent of the Richedit (A panel I placed in there for alignment purposes).
I mistakenly left out that fact in the question thinking it did not matter.
That said the following worked for me.

However I strongly favor Remy's architecturally more sound approach, and people struggling with this issue should try that approach first.

**In VCL.ComCtrls**

```
  TCustomRichEdit = class(TCustomMemo)
  private  //Why private !?
    procedure CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyRE); message CN_NOTIFY;
```

The solution is to interpose our own TRichEdit:

```
uses   
  ...., RichEdit;

type
  TRichEdit = class(ComCtrls.TRichEdit)
    procedure CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyRE); message CN_NOTIFY;
  end;  //never mind that its ancester is private, it will still work.

  TProgCorner = class(TForm)
```

I store the RichRdits in an array, so I can look them up by their `HWnd` without having to loop though all childcontrols of my form.

```
implementation

function TProgCorner.RichEditByHandle(Handle: HWnd): TRichEdit;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  //Keep track of the richedits in an array, initialized on creation.
  for i:= Low(RichEdits) to High(RichEdits) do begin
    if RichEdits[i].Handle = Handle then exit(RichEdits[i]);
  end;
  Result:= nil;
end;

procedure TRichEdit.CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyRE);
var
  p: TENLink;
  sURL: string;
  CE: TRichEdit;
begin
  if (Message.NMHdr.code = EN_LINK) then begin
    p:= TENLink(Pointer(TWMNotify(Message).NMHdr)^);
    if (p.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) then begin
      try
        //CE:= TRichEdit(ProgCorner.ActiveControl);
        //SendMessage(CE.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, Longint(@(p.chrg)));
        SendMessage(p.nmhdr.hwndFrom, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, Longint(@(p.chrg)));
        CE:= ProgCorner.RichEditByHandle(p.nmhdr.hwndFrom);
        if assigned(CE) then begin
          sURL:= CE.SelText;
          ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(sURL), 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        end;
      except
        {ignore}
      end;
    end;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Luckily the interposing of message handlers works even though the original is declared private.

Now it works. like a charm.

Below is a full copy of the unit for future reference:

```
unit ProgCorn;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, Menus, Clipbrd, LifeConst, Tabnotbk, LifeUtil,
  MyLinkLabel, RichEdit;

type
  TRichEdit = class(ComCtrls.TRichEdit)
    procedure CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyRE); message CN_NOTIFY;
  end;


  TProgCorner = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    TabbedNotebook1: TTabbedNotebook;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    Copy1: TMenuItem;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    RichEdit2: TRichEdit;
    RichEdit3: TRichEdit;
    RichEdit4: TRichEdit;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Copy1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    RichEdits: array[1..4] of TRichEdit;
    procedure InitRichEditURLDetection(RE: TRichEdit);
    function RichEditByHandle(Handle: HWnd): TRichEdit;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  ProgCorner: TProgCorner;


implementation

{$R *.DFM}

uses
  ShellAPI;

const
  AURL_ENABLEEAURLS = 8;
  AURL_ENABLEURL = 1;

procedure TProgCorner.InitRichEditURLDetection(RE: TRichEdit);
var
  mask: NativeInt;
begin
  mask := SendMessage(RE.Handle, EM_GETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
  SendMessage(RE.Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, mask or ENM_LINK);
  SendMessage(RE.Handle, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, {AURL_ENABLEEAURLS} AURL_ENABLEURL, 0);
end;



procedure TProgCorner.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProgCorner:= Self;
  InitRichEditURLDetection(RichEdit1);
  InitRichEditURLDetection(RichEdit2);
  InitRichEditURLDetection(RichEdit3);
  InitRichEditURLDetection(RichEdit4);
  RichEdits[1]:= RichEdit1;
  RichEdits[2]:= RichEdit2;
  RichEdits[3]:= RichEdit3;
  RichEdits[4]:= RichEdit4;

  //WordWarp should be set during runtime only, because
  //otherwise the text will not warp, but rather be cut off
  //before run time.
  RichEdit1.Text:= RichEdit1.Text + ' ';
  RichEdit2.Text:= RichEdit2.Text + ' ';
  RichEdit3.Text:= RichEdit3.Text + ' ';
  RichEdit4.Text:= RichEdit4.Text + ' ';
  RichEdit1.WordWrap:= true;
  RichEdit2.WordWrap:= true;
  RichEdit3.WordWrap:= true;
  RichEdit4.WordWrap:= true;
end;

procedure TProgCorner.Copy1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ActiveRichEdit: TRichEdit;
begin
  ActiveRichEdit:= TRichEdit(Self.FindComponent('RichEdit'+
    IntToStr(TabbedNotebook1.PageIndex+1)));
  with ActiveRichEdit do begin
    if SelText <> '' then Clipboard.AsText:= SelText
    else ClipBoard.AsText:= Lines.Text;
  end; {with}
end;

procedure TProgCorner.PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Copy1.Enabled:= true;
end;


procedure TProgCorner.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.HelpContext(4);
end;

{ TRichEdit }

function TProgCorner.RichEditByHandle(Handle: HWnd): TRichEdit;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i:= Low(RichEdits) to High(RichEdits) do begin
    if RichEdits[i].Handle = Handle then exit(RichEdits[i]);
  end;
  Result:= nil;
end;

procedure TRichEdit.CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyRE);
var
  p: TENLink;
  sURL: string;
  CE: TRichEdit;
begin
  //if (Message.Msg = WM_NOTIFY) then begin
    if (Message.NMHdr.code = EN_LINK) then begin
      p:= TENLink(Pointer(TWMNotify(Message).NMHdr)^);
      if (p.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) then begin
        try
          //CE:= TRichEdit(ProgCorner.ActiveControl);
          //SendMessage(CE.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, Longint(@(p.chrg)));
          SendMessage(p.nmhdr.hwndFrom, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, Longint(@(p.chrg)));
          CE:= ProgCorner.RichEditByHandle(p.nmhdr.hwndFrom);
          if assigned(CE) then begin
            sURL:= CE.SelText;
            ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(sURL), 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
          end;
        except
          {ignore}
        end;
      end;
    end;
  //end;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

Comment: "*The problem is that the WM_Notify message never reaches the mainform*" - yes, it does, **IF** the MainForm is the **immediate** parent of the RichEdit. "*Instead it gets intercepted by the CNNotify message of the RichEdit*" - that is where it will **eventually** end up, but it will show up in the RichEdit parent's `WndProc()` first, then work its way down to `TControl.Dispatch()`, which will pass it to `TWinControl.WMNotify()`, which will pass it to the RichEdit's `Perform()`, which will work its way down to `TCustomRichEdit.CNNotify()`.

Comment: "*I store the RichEdits in an array, so I can look them up by their HWnd without having to loop though all childcontrols of my form*" - there are easier ways. The VCL provides a link between `TWinControl` and its `HWND`. `WM_NOTIFY` contains the `HWND` of the control that sent it. In a `WM_NOTIFY` handler, you can pass that `HWND` to the `FindControl()` function in the `Controls` unit, and then type-cast the returned `TWinControl` to `TRichEdit`. But that is redundant in this case because inside of `CNNotify()` you have access to the `Self` pointer of the `TRichEdit` that is processing it.

Comment: You are not handling the case where the VCL may recreate the RichEdit's `HWND`.  Your interposer needs to override the `CreateWnd()` method to issue your `EM_SETEVENTMASK` and `EM_AUTOURLDETECT` messages every time the RichEdit creates a new `HWND` for itself.  Get rid of `TProgCorner.InitRichEditURLDetection()` altogether.

Comment: @RemyLebeau. I tried overriding `CreateWnd` (doesn't work at all). I also tried overriding `CreateWindowHandle`, that gets the Richedit to display the link, but then it breaks the CN_Notify event, that is the CN_Notify gets called with all sorts of stuff, but not with `EN_Link` messages.  I agree with you architecturally, but don't have the time to fully investigate this issue so I'll settle for what I've got right now.

Comment: what you have is **incomplete** and risks breakage eventually. You need to handle window recreation. Overriding `CreateWnd` works when done correctly.

Comment: OK, I'll investigate.